# iOS In-Call/Recording (Double Height) Status Bar Questions

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession, pjsip

I have the following questions:

1. Why do I have to add the Audio Background Mode to be able to see the in-call status bar .. why can I not see the bar only using VoIP?
2. If I am developing a VoIP application, with Backgrounds Mode set to
   VoIP and a background task helping me retain the call even in
   background or locked device, will activating Audio (background mode)
   for the red double height status bar be allowed upon uploading to
   the App Store? ( I do play some sounds that I want to be able to hear in the background (ringing and tone) using AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(..))
3. How can I change the background to green, from red (as I understand the VoIP/Call services should show green bars, and recording services should show red)
4. The VoIP part of the app is being managed by PJSIP .. this means I am responsible only for activating and deactivating the AVAudioSession upon connect/disconnect/hold actions .. does this mean I cannot show the green status bar?
5. How can I change the text from the status bar, and update it using my call duration?
6. The red status bar activates after I respond to the incoming call. Is there a way to show it as soon as my phone is ringing ? **

**(had to ask :( .. surely this isn't possible without a standard API .. I think this "showing of the status bar" is a reactive one-time action from when data starts transmitting/is recorder and the end of this process)

PS: I know there are duplicates .. but no one answered to the questions successfully .. in my opinion ..
[Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iOS%20double%20height%20status%20bar%20voip)

Code for configuring AVAudioSession and setting it active/inactive:

```
#pragma mark - AVAudioSession
-(AVAudioSession *) configureAVAudioSession {
    AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError* error = nil; BOOL success = NO;
    success = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error];
    if (error || !success){
        errorlog(@"categError: %@\n", error);
    } else {
        error=nil; //success = NO;
        success = [session setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error];
        if (error || !success){
            errorlog(@"modeError: %@\n", error);
        } else {
            error=nil; //success = NO;
            success = true; //[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error]; // None for Earpiece, Speaker for speaker
            if (error || !success){
                errorlog(@"OverrideToSpeaker ERR: %@\n", error);
            } else {
                error=nil; //success = NO;
                success = true; //[session setPreferredInput:[[session availableInputs] objectAtIndex:0] error:&error]; // Built-In Microphone
                if (error || !success){
                    errorlog(@"input ERR: %@\n", error);
                } else {
                    simplelog(@"\n");
                    if ([self setSessionActive])
                        return session;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

-(BOOL)setSessionActive {
    NSError *error=nil; BOOL success = NO;
    AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    success = [session setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];
    if (error || !success){
        errorlog(@"Session set to Active failed with error: %@\n", error);
        return NO;
    } else {
        log(@"Session set to Active");
        return YES;
    }
}

-(BOOL)setSessionInactive {
    NSError *error; BOOL success = NO;
    AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    success = [session setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];
    if (error || !success){
        errorlog(@"Session set to NON-Active failed with error: %@\n", error);
        return NO;
    } else {
        log(@"Session set to NON-Active");
        return YES;
    }
}
```

And the code which I use to play the ringing/tone audio files:

```
    NSURL *ringtonePath =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pathToRingtoneFilename ofType:pathToRingtoneExt]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) ringtonePath, &ringtoneID);
//...
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(ringtoneID);
//...
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(ringtoneID);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you found duplicates, you can actually quote them in your question. And please post your tried codes, screenshot, etc.

Comment: I just activate the AVAudioSession, and In the back I call a call(..) method, which resides in C, and from there the pjsip comes in and initializes the call. I can only give you the setting of the session and the activation method, the rest i'm afraid I cannot post :) - i'll update with the code